# Codeigniter - captcha flash data being not being saved when image loaded via ajax

Tags: codeigniter, jquery, captcha, session-cookies

I am using Codeigniter and using the Captcha plugin for user registration. All works fine until I have an ajax (jQuery) loading image on the same page that is used by the top nav bar. When this is included, the flash session vars appear to not get saved.

I can add the img to the HTML and all works fine, its only when it loads it via ajax that is breaks.

Im guessing this is due to another request firing for the image, and the session vars get overwritten.

Any thoughts on how I can work around this?

Comment: i think the flashdata relies on your header settings - and since your using ajax you cant set flashdata...

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The flash data is being set in the controller, and not in the ajax image load request. It appears that the image load breaks the setting of the flash data, even thought he image load is a static file, so should not even hit Codeigniter. Im going to see if i can reproduce a test case.